# Quickest way to add variable text from a text file to a JSON file in specific places

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, json

I'm trying to find the easiest and quickest way to fetch a list of names in different lines from a text file and appending them to a specific field in a structured JSON file that repeats itself over and over again.

Is there some plugin for Visual Studio Code that can do the trick? Or any other method/tool I can use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is both heavily opinion-based and also directly asking for software recommendation, which is off-topic here. Ask there instead https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/unanswered

Comment: In what language? Are you writing code? Do you want software to do the work for you?